# How to properly test kafkaTemplate.send() within a function in Junit5?

Tags: apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-kafka, junit5

I'm learning how to write tests and especially tests that have a producer in it. I cannot post all the classes because it's HUGE (and not mine, I should just practice by changing the test to work with KafkaTemplate). I'm lost as to how a call like this should be tested.

I'm getting a NPE because of a producer.send("topic", JsonObject) that is in the function I'm testing. The functions is built like so:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate;

public EventDto sendEvent(Event event) {
       EventDto eventToSend = this.dtoMapper.mapToDto(event, SomeEvent.class);
       this.kafkaTemplate.send("topic",eventToSend);
       return eventToSend;
   }
```

in the unit test it's like this (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
@Test
void testSendEvent() {
      //omitted lines regarding second assert that works
      
      EventProducer producer = new EventProducer(something);
      EventDto dto = producer.sendEvent(Event.newBuilder().build());
      assertThat(dto).isNotNull();
      //there is a second assert here that passes, nothing to do with kafka
}
```

We have Mockito and I assume I need to mock the KafkaTemplate somehow. But I'm not quite getting how I can "direct" the sendEvent to use the KafkaTemplate within the `producer.sendEvent()` call?

Solution edit: I changed the `@Autowired` to injecting it with the constructor instead. Works well! Here is the full class and method now

```
@Service
public class EventProducer implements EventProducerInterface {

   private final DtoMapper dtoMapper;
   private KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate;

   @Autowired
   public EventProducer (KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate, IDtoMapper dtoMapper) {
          Assert.notNull(dtoMapper, "dtoMapper must not be null");
          this.dtoMapper = dtoMapper;
          this.kafkaTemplate=kafkaTemplate;
       }

   public EventDto sendEvent(Event event) {
       EventDto eventToSend = this.dtoMapper.mapToDto(event, EventDto.class);
       this.kafkaTemplate.send("output-topic",eventToSend);
       return eventToSend;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use constructor injection instead of `@Autowired`:

```java
private KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate;

public EventProducer(KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate, something) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public EventDto sendEvent(Event event) {
       EventDto eventToSend = this.dtoMapper.mapToDto(event, SomeEvent.class);
       this.kafkaTemplate.send("topic",eventToSend);
       return eventToSend;
}
```

This way you can inject a mock in your tests:

```java
@Test
void testSendEvent() {
      //omitted lines regarding second assert that works
      KafkaTemplate<<String,EventDto>> templateMock = mock(KafkaTemplate.class);
      EventProducer producer = new EventProducer(templateMock, something);
      EventDto dto = producer.sendEvent(Event.newBuilder().build());
      assertThat(dto).isNotNull();
      //there is a second assert here that passes, nothing to do with kafka
}
```

If you can't change the class' constructor, you can provide a mock using `@MockBean`:

```java
@MockBean
KafkaTemplate<String,EventDto> kafkaTemplate;

@Test
void testSendEvent() {
      //omitted lines regarding second assert that works
      
      EventProducer producer = new EventProducer(something);
      EventDto dto = producer.sendEvent(Event.newBuilder().build());
      assertThat(dto).isNotNull();
      //there is a second assert here that passes, nothing to do with kafka
}
```

But there's something odd with this design - does the `EventProducer` class have `@Autowired` and constructor arguments? Autowiring only works on beans, and usually either the class has a default constructor and `@Autowired` dependencies, or injects everything through the constructor.

If those options I present do not work for you, please add more details on the class' constructor and overall design.

Comment: Thanks! I made a second constructor that injects the KafkaTemplate and that seems to work. But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it some other way? Or if this is even a good way to do it? @MockBean didn't seem to do anything for me. I wonder if it's because of how the class is made/connected with other things? Please see my edit if it helps.

Comment: Also, it seems doing a second constructor breaks the actual service (but hey the test works) :( should I not have overloaded it perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for adding more info. I don't see the `KafkaTemplate` in the `EventProducer` class. Is the `sendEvent` method part of that class?

Comment: yes, the sendEvent is in there as well as the KafkaTemplate, I didn't include them in the edit to save some space. But I added the ```@Autowired``` Template myself as well as the ```.send()```

The constructor way seems to be the nicest though, and I assume it is the best practice instead of autowired?

Comment: Yes, constructor injection [is preffered](https://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) over @Autowired. I'm not sure I understand though - is everything working now? If not, can you edit your question to include the `EventProducer ` sample with both `KafkaTemplate` and `DtoMapper`, so we can see how they're both injected? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember to avoid autowiring everything in the future. I've made an edit to show the class in question for whoever might be interested in the future. Thanks again!

as for the DtoMapper, I also don't understand how they work. It's a strange little microservice I have on my hands now.